# change color for each area

Tags: xml

I want a way to somehow only color the area light blue or light green if there is a value in the cell. Otherwise, i want to keep it white. How do i do this? For instance, in the code bellow, if there is a pet without an ID, i want to leave that pet's ID cell white in background color. Otherwise, if the pet has an ID, i want to change that pet's ID cell to light blue.

**Here is my code below:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Pets/Pet">
        <TR>

            <TD BGCOLOR = "LIGHTBLUE">
                <FONT FACE = "COURIER" COLOR = "BLUE">
                <xsl:value-of select="PetID"/></FONT>
            </TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR = "LIGHTGREEN">
                <FONT FACE = "COURIER" COLOR = "BLUE">
                <xsl:value-of select="PetColorCode"/></FONT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like the following. I haven't tested this code but I will if you post some example XML

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(PetId) > 0">
            <TR>
                <TD BGCOLOR="LIGHTBLUE">
                    <FONT FACE="COURIER" COLOR="BLUE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PetID"/>
                    </FONT>
                </TD>
                <TD BGCOLOR="LIGHTGREEN">
                    <FONT FACE="COURIER" COLOR="BLUE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PetColorCode"/>
                    </FONT>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <TR>
                <TD BGCOLOR="WHITE">
                    <FONT FACE="COURIER" COLOR="BLUE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PetID"/>
                    </FONT>
                </TD>
                <TD BGCOLOR="WHITE">
                    <FONT FACE="COURIER" COLOR="BLUE">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PetColorCode"/>
                    </FONT>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```